# Power BI Premium loading visuals slower than Pro

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I'm working on a project that utilizes a combination of Power Apps, Excel, and Power BI. The user inputs data into Power Apps, calculations are done in Excel, and the data is sent to Power BI for visuals. In our Premium workspace, the Power BI dashboard visuals take forever to load (sometimes >5 mins); however when we change the workspace to Pro, the visuals load immediately. Our team wants the Premium workspace to allow for 48 refreshes daily, but only the Pro version is loading in a timely manner. Does anyone know why this loading issue may be occurring, and if there is a workaround? Thanks!

FWIW our Excel file is in a shared drive folder (not in Sharepoint since that loading time was too long regardless of workspace).